# UltraEdit for Multiple Terminal Sessions

Tags: user-management, users, windows-terminal-services

If you are using/installing UltraEdit a lot, you might have experienced that you can register it for only one user on the machine...

But as I am setting up a Windows 2008 Terminal Server for several users to access remotely, it is a PAIN to register the key in UltraEdit on every user account.

Every other piece of software just work, what has been gone wrong with UltraEdit? / Is there a plausible fix for this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the license file "uedit32.reg" into the "%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\IDMComp" directory for each user. Easiest way to do this is probably a vbscript wrapper when the application is launched.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the solution to the problem!

How did you find that out if I may ask?

Answer (score 1):

Have you contacted the vendor?  It sounds like the application isn't really designed for use in a terminal server environment, which makes me wonder if you have licensed it properly for a TS.

The ultraedit registration is most likely adding something to the registry.  You could probably figure out what it is adding with something like [regmon](http://live.sysinternals.com/Regmon.exe).  Then simply add that bit to everyone's registry as part of the login script.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing and registering it using the "Install Applications on Terminal Server" selection in the control panel? You could also just run this from a command line before registering:

```
change user /install
```

Just make sure to run this afterward:

```
change user /execute
```